# Draw transparent image in GraphicsContext (on a background thread) - Performance issues in collectionView with many visible cells

Tags: ios, swift, uigraphicscontext

so I've been trying to improve the drawing performance of my app. I'm developing an app for the iPad Pro. In some situations, there's a huge `collectionView` with dozens of cells (probably up to 50-60) that are visible simultaneously. Each cell contains 2 images: one "content" image (displaying what the user has set to be in that cell), and another one is a 80% transparent "overlay" image that's basically just adding a "glossy" effect to the cell.

There are many frames being dropped when scrolling through the `collectionView`, so I thought I'd draw the contents of the cell in a background thread, like this:

```
class Renderer {
        private lazy var glossyCover = { // the "overlay" image
            return UIImage(named: "glossCover")!
        }()

        public var renderedImage: UIImage? = nil // for caching

        public var hasRendered: Bool {
            return renderedImage != nil
        }

        // The model contains the image that this cell should display
        public func render(with model: MyModel, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

            model.cover.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

            // This makes the collectionView stutter pretty badly, when not commented out
            glossyCover.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

            renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return renderedImage
        }
    }
```

---

```
...
// This is inside the "cellForItem(at:)" method of the collectionView.
onDemandRenderingItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

    // strongSelf.renderer is the Renderer class from above. I pretty much have one instance for every cell (I'm using IGListKit, so that's not entirely correct, but there are enough instances of it for every cell)
    guard let preparedCell = strongSelf.renderer.render(with: model, size: size) else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.imageView.image = preparedCell
    }
}      

// dispatch item
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async(execute: onDemandRenderingItem!)

// return cell and stuff 
return cell
...
```

It's a simple class that draws the two images into a context and returns the image. I then just add this image to the cell's `imageView` I set up.

However, it's not working perfectly fine.

Without drawing the "glossy overlay", it's almost perfect. You can scroll as fast as you want, and it stays perfectly smooth. Almost always, at least. Sometimes, it stutters briefly.

Though, as soon as I also draw the "glossy overlay", it starts to stutter pretty badly. Not as bad as it was before I did it in the background, but it's noticeable.

I have two questions:

1. Why does it stutter at all? I'm doing it in the background. Why is it affecting the main queue? Setting the finished image shouldn't be that expensive, right?
2. Why is drawing an almost completely transparent image bad for the performance? (Again, it should just take a bit longer to render, but it's still on a background thread)

Thanks for any help.

*PS: I hope I gave enough information for you to understand the questions. The actual methods and classes in my app are far more complex. I tried to take out everything that isn't related to my problem, to make it more compact. Please tell me if you need any more info.*

Comment: Any chance you can post a clip of the scrolling performance?

Comment: I can try, yes.

Comment: Where is `hasRendered` called? If it's not, then you're re-rendering each cell's image *every time* the cell is drawn. And it looks like your renderer instance is on the `collectionView` itself, which makes caching (if it's working) pointless anyway. It sounds like you need a 1:1 ratio of renderers to cell models, and if that's the case, the rendering should be called for all models on a background thread *once*.

Comment: I do cache them. it didn't change anything though, so I removed it from the snippets I posted. I mean, it shouldn't even matter, I think. Every time a cell is requested, it instantly returns an empty cell that will be filled after the images have been drawn. It shouldn't impact performance. As for the 1:1 ratio: I do have it. I'm using `IGListKit`, every cell has its own `ListSectionController`, which manages the cell. Each section controller has its own renderer.

Comment: Here's the video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zd5tdlfqgjrfg2g/ezgif.com-video-cutter.mp4?dl=0

It's a bit hard to see on a video, though. I don't know why Dropbox plays it in slo-mo. The video is not.